# How to interact with qml item values after passing them to cpp?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to get values of items in `qml` to my `cpp` code, from there I want to add those values to CAN messages and send them via CAN bus.

So far, I can successfully get the values and states of many `qml` items to my `cpp`. Also, I can transmit CAN messages on to the CAN bus with static values. However, some of these values shouldn't be static but dynamically updated with values of items in `qml`.

Here is *backend.h*:

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QCanBusDevice>

class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int elemVal READ getElemVal WRITE setElemVal NOTIFY elemValChanged)

public:
    explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    //elemVal
    int getElemVal();
    void setElemVal(const int &elemVal);
    int m_elemVal;

    //can
    void run();
    void oneShotConnectCan();
    QCanBusDevice *m_canDevice = nullptr;

signals:
    void elemValChanged();

public slots:
    void sendCanFrame();
};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

Here is *backend.cpp*:

```
BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

//elemVal get set
int BackEnd::getElemVal()
{
    return m_elemVal;
}

void BackEnd::setElemVal(const int &elemVal)
{
    if(elemVal == m_elemVal)
        return;

    m_elemVal = elemVal;
    emit elemValChanged();
    qDebug() << "elemVal is: " << m_elemVal;
}
//end of elemVal get set

... 
CAN Bus initialization
...

void BackEnd::sendCanFrame()
{
    quint32 frameid = 131;
    QByteArray payload;
    payload[0] = 0x04;
    payload[1] = 0x03;
    payload[2] = m_elemVal;

    QCanBusFrame testFrame(frameid, payload);
    testFrame.setFrameType(QCanBusFrame::DataFrame);

    m_canDevice->writeFrame(testFrame);
    if (m_canDevice->writeFrame(testFrame)) {
    qDebug() << "test frame: " << testFrame.toString();
    }
    else {
        qFatal("Write failed");
    }
}
```

Here is *main.cpp*:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<BackEnd>("io.qt.examples.backend", 1, 0, "BackEnd");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    BackEnd m_can;
    m_can.oneShotConnectCan(); //creating CAN device
    m_can.run(); //sending the CAN message

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is *main.qml* file:

```
Window {
    id: window
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    onWindowStateChanged: {
        console.log( "onWindowStateChanged (Window), state: " + windowState );
    }

    BackEnd{
        id: backend
    }

    Dial {
        id: dial
        x: 181
        y: 38
        stepSize: 1
        to: 255
        value: backend.elemVal
        onValueChanged: backend.elemVal = value
    }
}
```

The actual output of qDebug is like this:

```
elemVal is:  0
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 05"
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 05"
elemVal is:  1
elemVal is:  2
elemVal is:  3
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 05"
elemVal is:  4
elemVal is:  5
elemVal is:  6
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 05"
```

How I expect it to be:

```
elemVal is:  0
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 00"
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 00"
elemVal is:  1
elemVal is:  2
elemVal is:  3
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 03"
elemVal is:  4
elemVal is:  5
elemVal is:  6
test frame :  "     083   [3]  04 03 06"
```

The third byte of the message, which is 05 in actual output, should be changing dynamically with `m_elemVal` variable which is connected to dial in `qml`. Although I can read and write the value of `m_elemVal`, I cannot write it to my CAN message.

Sorry if the post is too long, tried to be as specific as possible.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Not too long, it's actually detailed! +1
I don't get how `sendCanFrame` is called?

Comment: @Amfasis sendCanFrame is called in the run() function which I didn't include here. It's actually in the backend.cpp which is called by Connect via a timer's timeout signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Backend object that you created in QML

```
BackEnd {
    id: backend
}
```

and it is different from the one created in C++:

```cpp
BackEnd m_can;
```

There are several possible solutions:

#### 1. Export a Backend object through setContextProperty()

The advantage over the other proposed solution is that now the backend object can be accessed from any QML like `console.log()`.

```cpp
#include <QQmlContext>
// ...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    BackEnd m_can;
    m_can.oneShotConnectCan(); //creating CAN device
    m_can.run(); //sending the CAN message

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", &m_can);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

*.qml

```
Window {
    id: window
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    onWindowStateChanged: {
        console.log( "onWindowStateChanged (Window), state: " + windowState );
    }

    Dial {
        id: dial
        x: 181
        y: 38
        stepSize: 1
        to: 255
        onValueChanged: backend.elemVal = value
    }
}
```

An advantage compared to the other answer does not use the old connection style that can generate problems, since its validation is done at run time and not at compile time. In addition, the code is dependent on the QML structure.

I also assume that you want to send a frame when an elemVal changes, so the ideal is to make a connection between the signal between elemValChanged and sendCanFrame():

```cpp
BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(this, &Backend::elemValChanged, this, &Backend::sendCanFrame);
}
```

#### 2. Create a QML Type

Sometimes it is necessary to start certain resources after creating the object, in those cases you can use Component.onCompleted in QML or use QQmlParserStatus, in this case I will use the second method.

*.h

```cpp
class BackEnd : public QObject, public QQmlParserStatus
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QQmlParserStatus)
    Q_PROPERTY(int elemVal READ getElemVal WRITE setElemVal NOTIFY elemValChanged)
public:
    explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void classBegin();
    void componentComplete();
    //elemVal
    int getElemVal();
    void setElemVal(const int &elemVal);
signals:
    void elemValChanged();

public slots:
    void sendCanFrame();
private:
    //can
    void run();
    void oneShotConnectCan();
    QCanBusDevice *m_canDevice = nullptr;
    int m_elemVal;
};
```

*.cpp

```cpp
BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(this, &Backend::elemValChanged, this, &Backend::sendCanFrame);
}

void BackEnd::classBegin(){}
void BackEnd::componentComplete()
{
    oneShotConnectCan(); //creating CAN device
    run()
}

//elemVal get set
int BackEnd::getElemVal()
{
    return m_elemVal;
}

void BackEnd::setElemVal(const int &elemVal)
{
    if(elemVal == m_elemVal)
        return;

    m_elemVal = elemVal;
    emit elemValChanged();
    qDebug() << "elemVal is: " << m_elemVal;
}
//end of elemVal get set

// ... 
// CAN Bus initialization
// ...

void BackEnd::sendCanFrame()
{
    quint32 frameid = 131;
    QByteArray payload;
    payload[0] = 0x04;
    payload[1] = 0x03;
    payload[2] = m_elemVal;

    QCanBusFrame testFrame(frameid, payload);
    testFrame.setFrameType(QCanBusFrame::DataFrame);

    m_canDevice->writeFrame(testFrame);
    if (m_canDevice->writeFrame(testFrame)) {
    qDebug() << "test frame: " << testFrame.toString();
    }
    else {
        qFatal("Write failed");
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
static void registerTypes()
{
    qmlRegisterType<BackEnd>("io.qt.examples.backend", 1, 0, "BackEnd");
}

Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION(registerTypes)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

*.qml

```
Window {
    id: window
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    onWindowStateChanged: {
        console.log( "onWindowStateChanged (Window), state: " + windowState );
    }

    BackEnd{
        id: backend
        elemVal : dial.value
    }

    Dial {
        id: dial
        x: 181
        y: 38
        stepSize: 1
        to: 255
        Component.onCompleted: value = backend.elemVal
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your first solution has solved the issue. But more importantly, I got a better understanding of the concept as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

- Create an invokable method that you invoke once your QML Window is instanciated
- Invoke the method you use to send messages when elemval changes:

backend.h:

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QCanBusDevice>

class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);

        // elemVal
        Q_PROPERTY(int elemVal READ getElemVal WRITE setElemVal NOTIFY elemValChanged)
        int getElemVal();
        void setElemVal(const int &elemVal);
        int m_elemVal;

        // The method for your first message
        Q_INVOKABLE void sendFirstMessage();

        //can
        void run();
        void oneShotConnectCan();
        QCanBusDevice *m_canDevice = nullptr;

    signals:
        void elemValChanged();

    public slots:
        void sendCanFrame();
};
```

backend.cpp:

```
// Your actual backend.cpp here.

void Backend::sendFirstMessage() {
    oneShotConnectCan(); //creating CAN device
    run(); //sending the CAN message
}
```

main.qml:

```
Window {
    id: window
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    onWindowStateChanged: {
        console.log( "onWindowStateChanged (Window), state: " + windowState );
    }

    BackEnd{
        id: backend
        elemVal: dial.value
        onElemValChanged: backend.sendCanFrame()    // You should code this on the C++ side.
    }

    Dial {
        id: dial
        x: 181
        y: 38
        stepSize: 1
        to: 255
    }

    // Wiil be executed when window instanciation has just ended.
    Component.onCompleted: backend.sendFirstMessage();
}
```

For further information about `Component.onCompleted`, please have a look at this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal.

Avoid manipulating QML from the C++ side. Decouple backend and frontend as much as you can (that's why I have downvoted both eyllanesc and Romha Korev answers).

Comment: In which part do I manipulate a QML object from C++? I export a C++ object to QML.

Comment: In `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend");`. You inject an obscure "backend" (for QML) from C++ to QML. That's not a proper and decoupled way to make C++ and QML interact to my mind.

Comment: It is not obscure backend, it is a QObject that is recognized by all QML, I recommend reading [Best Practices for QML and Qt Quick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#pushing-references-to-qml)

Comment: Where did you get that is "obscure"? I never read about that adjective in Qt's docs.

Comment: And it is totally decoupled, I have only injected a QObject that for QML is a global object that its elimination does not depend does not affect QML: *In the example above, we set a context property on the root context to expose the C++ object to QML. This means that the property is available to every component loaded by the engine. Context properties are useful for objects that must be available as soon as the QML is loaded and cannot be instantiated in QML.*  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#pushing-references-to-qml

Comment: That is not the style that you like does not imply that it is wrong. So far you have not pointed out any technical disadvantages. IMHO your answer and mine are 2 different but adequate options, which in my point of view has no technical problems. You are seeing Backend as a new QtObject QML and I am seeing it as a global object. Unlike the other answer that is clearly accessing an object that can be eliminated by QML and therefore could access an unallocated memory and is highly dependent on the structure of QML.

Comment: It cames out of nowhere on the QML side. For example, what is "backend" for frontend QML developers, for people who never have a look to C++ code? With qmlRegisterType it is a C++ object exposed to QML, which belongs to a very QML library. But with setContext, it is just a "thing called backend".

Comment: That's if you only consider that you want to use only QML, but clearly the OP is using a combination of C++ and QML. For QML developers the backend can is a global object like to `console` in `console.log()`. When you use qmlRegisterType you are registering a new type in QML: *QML Register Type*, if you think it is a C++ object then all QML is a C++ object since the types like Loader, TableView, Item, QtObject, etc are registered using qmlRegisterType